# My return of height of a UILabel is never accurate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to capture the height of my UILabel so that I can dynamically set the height of it's cell, but it never returns the right height, and effectually, my content is always truncated and appended with ellipses.

My code :

```
let height   = String(page.valueForKey(subject)).heightWithConstrainedWidth(self.view.frame.width - 30, font: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0))

// and at the bottom of my class..

// Custom functions
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.max)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRectWithSize(constraintRect, options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

It definitely makes a valiant attempt because it returns some sort of dynamic number that is relatively large, but the number is always short and never accurate.

Is there something glaringly inapropriate about how I'm extracting height? Is there a better way to perform this?

---

Per Matt's response, I updated to measure the label as so :

```
// Custom functions
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,width, CGFloat.max))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = self
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
    }
}
```

But it's still not quite big enough..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine for what it does. The problem is merely that a label is not a string. You are finding the height of a string. That isn't what you want to do. You want to find the height of a label! There is more to a UILabel, after all, than just the string it contains. The UILabel is taller than the string. You are not taking that into account.

Comment: Salutations! That makes a huge amount of sense. I'm under the impression that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ( where I instantiate my UILabel ) is called *after* `heightForRowAtIndexPath` .. I'd rather not instantiate a UILabel just to measure it, then never use it, and recreate it again later. Is there a way to send the end result of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method? I guess I could just update my `extension String` to return the size of the string within a UILabel..

Comment: So is the problem actually that you don't know how to size a cell based on its contained label? Maybe that's what you should have asked!

Comment: Here's a downloadable example that consists of cells with labels of different heights. No code needed! https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch08p424variableHeights

Comment: Ah thanks so much!! Super appreciate your works. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wow this solution is amazing. Thanks again so much. I was just able to knock down a ton of useless code! Thanks!!